# find the length of the longest consecutive series of numbers

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array like this `[1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1]` I'd like to find the length of the longest consecutive series of either 1s or -1s. In the example, it should be 3

Comment: Do you want a `numpy` solution or a pure-python solution is okay? It's trivial using `itertools.groupby`...

Comment: So the output in this case should be 2 (-1-1) right ?...ord is there just a "," missing and you actually want 3 (1,1,1) ?

Comment: @Bakuriu all pure-python solutions are numpy solutions.  The only twist is that sometimes numpy-specific solutions are much nicer or much faster.

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala That solution only works for bits (although it is similar) it is not the same

Answer (score 19):

In pure Python

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> L = [1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1]
>>> max(sum(1 for i in g) for k,g in groupby(L))
3
```

Comment: Can't get any simpler than this. +1

Comment: Nice use of itertools!

Comment: @jszakmeister, any time the problem includes the word "consecutive", `groupby()` should be the first thing you thing about

Comment: Brilliant answer! And concise as well!

Answer (score 6):

Similar to the answer by [@AlexMartelli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1066838/1219006)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> nums = np.array([1,1,1,-1-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1])
>>> run_ends = np.where(np.diff(nums))[0] + 1
>>> np.diff(np.hstack((0, run_ends, nums.size))).max()
3
```