# Track value changes in a repetitive list in Python

Tags: python, list, repeat

I have a list with repeating values as shown below:

```
x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

This list is generated from a pattern matching regular expression (not shown here). The list is guaranteed to have repeating values (many, many repeats - hundreds, if not thousands), and is never randomly arranged because that's what the regex is matching each time.

What I want is to ***track the list indices at which the entries change from the previous value***. So for the above list `x`, I want to obtain a change-tracking list `[3, 6]` indicating that `x[3]` and `x[6]` are different from their previous entries in the list.

I managed to do this, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way. Here's my code:

```
x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]

flag = []
for index, item in enumerate(x):
    if index != 0:
        if x[index] != x[index-1]:
            flag.append(index)

print flag
```

**Output**: `[3, 6]`

**Question**: Is there a cleaner way to do what I want, in fewer lines of code?

Comment: well looking at it you could get rid of `lag` by just using `index-1` in your second if statement, and change the second if to `!=` and that way you can drop the else and move that code up to the if

Comment: @JamesKent That's a good idea. I updated the question and the code. Thanks.

Comment: You already have `item`, so you don't need to access `x[index]` again for the comparison to `x[index-1]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [find length of sequences of identical values in a numpy array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066758/find-length-of-sequences-of-identical-values-in-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be done using a list comprehension, with a `range` function

```
>>> x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
>>> [i for i in range(1,len(x)) if x[i]!=x[i-1] ]
[3, 6]
>>> x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
>>> [i for i in range(1,len(x)) if x[i]!=x[i-1] ]
[3, 6]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this using [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip), [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) and a list-comprehension:

```
from itertools import izip, tee
it1, it2 = tee(x)
next(it2)
print [i for i, (a, b) in enumerate(izip(it1, it2), 1) if a != b]
# [3, 6]
```

Another alternative using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) on [`enumerate(x)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate). `groupby` groups similar items together, so all we need is the index of first item of each group except the first one:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
it = (next(g)[0] for k, g in groupby(enumerate(x), itemgetter(1)))
next(it) # drop the first group
print list(it)
# [3, 6]
```

If NumPy is an option:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.where(np.diff(x) != 0)[0] + 1
array([3, 6])
```

Comment: I was thinking `list(accumulate(len(list(g)) for k,g in groupby(x)))[:-1]` before I came to my senses..

Answer (score 2):

instead multi-indexing that has `O(n)` complexity you can use an iterator to check for the next element in list :

```
>>> x =[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
>>> i_x=iter(x[1:])
>>> [i for i,j in enumerate(x[:-1],1) if j!=next(i_x)]
[3, 6]
```

Comment: This is quadratic runtime, and it does not handle the case `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]` correctly.

Comment: @SvenMarnach +1, I was against the use of `set` for this very reason.

Answer (score 2):

I'm here to add the obligatory answer that contains a list comprehension.

```
flag = [i+1 for i, value in enumerate(x[1:]) if (x[i] != value)]
```

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) is what you are looking for:

```
from itertools import islice, izip_longest

flag = []
leader, trailer = islice(iter(x), 1), iter(x)
for i, (current, previous) in enumerate(izip_longest(leader, trailer)):
    # Skip comparing the last entry to nothing
    # If None is a valid value use a different sentinel for izip_longest
    if leader is None:
        continue
    if current != previous:
        flag.append(i)
```