# Average Number of Repeating Patterns with Numpy

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I have an arbitrary array with only binary values- say:

```
a = np.array([1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,])
```

What would be the most efficient way to count average length of sequences of 1s array?  Eg. In this example, it would be (1 + 8 + 2)/3.

Comment: Complexity-wise: just iterate over all values and use some active/inactive counter. Combine with a one-pass mean-calculation and you got an O(n) algorithm which is also the lower bound (because you need to look at all elements at least once).

Comment: I see.  Hmm, was wondering if numpy had an internal function which could do pattern counting of some sort.  Thank you, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure easiest, but one alternative is

```
np.mean([len(list(v)) for k,v in itertools.groupby(a) if k])

3.6666666666666665
```

**Explanation**
`groupby` groups adjacent equal values together, we filter only ones (`if k`), the list comprehension `[...]` creates the list of the lengths of sub sequences of ones, i.e. `[1,8,2]`, and `mean` computes the average value.

Comment: This one looks really nice.  Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but do you think you could explain what is going on in this code?  I have never used itertools before.

Answer (score 2):

For an all numpy solution, you can use Alex Martelli's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1066838/298607) like so:

```
def runs_of_ones_array(bits):
    # make sure all runs of ones are well-bounded
    bounded = np.hstack(([0], bits, [0]))
    # get 1 at run starts and -1 at run ends
    difs = np.diff(bounded)
    run_starts, = np.where(difs > 0)
    run_ends, = np.where(difs < 0)
    return run_ends - run_starts

>>> a=np.array([1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,])
>>> b=runs_of_ones_array(a)
>>> float(sum(b))/len(b)
3.66666666667
```