# Comparing to the next/previous values in loop python dataframe

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, comparison

How to compare values to next or previous items in loop?
I need to summarize consecutive repetitinos of occurences in columns.

After that I need to create "frequency table" so the dfoutput schould looks like on the bottom picture.

This code doesn't work because I can't compare to another item.

Maybe there is another, simple way to do this without looping?

```
sumrep=0

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'1' : [0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0],'2' : [0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0]})
df.index= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]   # It will be easier to assign repetitions in output df - index will be equal to number of repetitions

dfoutput = pd.DataFrame(0,index=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],columns=['1','2'])

#example for column 1
for val1 in df.columns[1]:                           
    if val1 == 1 and val1 ==0:   #can't find the way to check NEXT val1 (one row below) in column 1 :/
        if sumrep==0:            
            dfoutput.loc[1,1]=dfoutput.loc[1,1]+1   #count only SINGLE occurences of values and assign it to proper row number 1 in dfoutput
        if sumrep>0:
            dfoutput.loc[sumrep,1]=dfoutput.loc[sumrep,1]+1   #count repeated occurences greater then 1 and assign them to proper row in dfoutput
            sumrep=0
    elif val1 == 1 and df[val1+1]==1 :
        sumrep=sumrep+1
```

Desired output table for column 1 - dfoutput:

[image]

I don't undestand why there is no any simple method to move around dataframe like offset function in VBA in Excel:/

Comment: so you want to count 1s row wise ? Why is dfoutput all zero ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function defined [here](https://gist.github.com/nvictus/66627b580c13068589957d6ab0919e66) to perform fast run-length-encoding:

> ```
> import numpy as np
>
>
> def rlencode(x, dropna=False):
>     """
>     Run length encoding.
>     Based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/32681075, which is based on the rle 
>     function from R.
>
>     Parameters
>     ----------
>     x : 1D array_like
>         Input array to encode
>     dropna: bool, optional
>         Drop all runs of NaNs.
>
>     Returns
>     -------
>     start positions, run lengths, run values
>
>     """
>     where = np.flatnonzero
>     x = np.asarray(x)
>     n = len(x)
>     if n == 0:
>         return (np.array([], dtype=int), 
>                 np.array([], dtype=int), 
>                 np.array([], dtype=x.dtype))
>
>     starts = np.r_[0, where(~np.isclose(x[1:], x[:-1], equal_nan=True)) + 1]
>     lengths = np.diff(np.r_[starts, n])
>     values = x[starts]
>
>     if dropna:
>         mask = ~np.isnan(values)
>         starts, lengths, values = starts[mask], lengths[mask], values[mask]
>
>     return starts, lengths, values
> ```

With this function your task becomes a lot easier:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from functools import partial

def get_frequency_of_runs(col, value=1, index=None):
     _, lengths, values = rlencode(col)
     return pd.Series(Counter(lengths[np.where(values == value)]), index=index)

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'1': [0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0],
                        '2': [0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0]})
df.apply(partial(get_frequency_of_runs, index=df.index)).fillna(0)
#       1    2
# 0   0.0  0.0
# 1   1.0  2.0
# 2   2.0  1.0
# 3   0.0  0.0
# 4   1.0  1.0
# 5   0.0  0.0
# 6   0.0  0.0
# 7   0.0  0.0
# 8   0.0  0.0
# 9   0.0  0.0
# 10  0.0  0.0
# 11  0.0  0.0
# 12  0.0  0.0
# 13  0.0  0.0
# 14  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help. I'll try to adapt this and undestand it but I think that will be very difficult. I've been playing with Python for about 20-30hrs till now:) If you have andy idea how to change my loop I'll be greatfull, but I'll try to run over your idea anyway:) Thank you for your time!