# Find Consecutive Repeats of Specific Length in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

Say that I have a NumPy array:

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 15])
```

And I have a length `m = 2` that the user specifies in order to see if there are any repeats of that length within the time series. In this case, the repeats of length `m = 2` are:

```
[2, 2]
[5, 5]
[9, 9]
[9, 9]
[13, 13]
```

And the user can change this to `m = 3` and the repeats of length `m = 3` are:

```
[9, 9, 9]
[13, 13, 13]
```

I need a function that either returns the index of where a repeat is found or `None`. So, for `m = 3` the function would return the following NumPy array of starting indices:

```
[11, 17]
```

And for `m = 4` the function would return `None`. What's the cleanest and fastest way to accomplish this?

**Update**
Note that the array does not have to be sorted and we are ***not*** interested in the result after a sort. We only want the result from the unsorted array. Your result for `m = 2` should be the same for this array:

```
b = np.array([0, 11, 2, 2, 3, 40, 5, 5, 16, 7, 80, 9, 9, 9, 1, 11, 12, 13, 13, 13, 4, 5])
```

Comment: Is `a` always sorted?

Comment: And, would it be `(2, 6, 11, 12, 17, 18)` for `m=2`?

Comment: Great questions. `a` is NEVER sorted and, yes, that is the returned array for `m = 2`

Comment: Can we sorted before?

Comment: Or it's impossible to sort the array?

Comment: It's not possible to sort but it's also not necessary. I'm not interested in repeats after a sort. I'm only interested in consecutive repeats as the array is.

Comment: Ok! So the solution that i posted should work!

Comment: @Divakar it looks like one of your previous solutions to a similar problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58221268/count-number-of-repeated-elements-in-a-row-in-a-numpy-array) is close or at least somewhat related. In my case, I need (1) indices and (2) the ability to find repeats of a specific length

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find length of sequences of identical values in a numpy array (run length encoding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066758/find-length-of-sequences-of-identical-values-in-a-numpy-array-run-length-encodi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1**

We could leverage [`1D convolution`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) for a vectorized solution -

```
def consec_repeat_starts(a, n):
    N = n-1
    m = a[:-1]==a[1:]
    return np.flatnonzero(np.convolve(m,np.ones(N, dtype=int))==N)-N+1
```

Sample runs -

```
In [286]: a
Out[286]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  2,  3,  4,  5,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  9,  9, 10, 11, 12,
       13, 13, 13, 14, 15])

In [287]: consec_repeat_starts(a, 2)
Out[287]: array([ 2,  6, 11, 12, 17, 18])

In [288]: consec_repeat_starts(a, 3)
Out[288]: array([11, 17])

In [289]: consec_repeat_starts(a, 4)
Out[289]: array([], dtype=int64)
```

**Approach #2**

We could also make use of `binary-erosion` -

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_erosion

def consec_repeat_starts_v2(a, n):
    N = n-1
    m = a[:-1]==a[1:]
    return np.flatnonzero(binary_erosion(m,[1]*N))-(N//2)
```

Comment: Dang, @Divakar! Again, your solution(s) is simple, elegant, and I've learned a ton in only a few lines of code. Thank you!

Comment: do the answers matter if the input array are `np.float64` instead?

Comment: @slaw Shouldn't. It would look for exact duplicates, so with floating point math if you are closeness, you need to bring in tolerance when comparing.

Comment: I should probably ask this in another question but after you get the indices, for each repeat sequence (starting at each index), is there a fast way to to then find all matches of that repeat sequence and return the index for those matches? So, if the array were `[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 2, 2]`, `consec_repeat_starts` would return `[2, 6, 8, 11, 13]`. Then, for each unique type of repeat sequence (i.e., `[2, 2]` and `[5, 5]`) I want to return something like the repeat followed by the indices for where the repeat is located `([2, 2], [2, 6, 13]), ([5, 5], [8, 11])`

Comment: @slaw Yeah, that would involve some more work. Better to ask a new question, I think.

Comment: Okay, I've reposted the question here if you wouldn't mind taking a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59667326/finding-indices-for-repeat-sequences-in-numpy-array

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with this solution, maybe it's not the cleanest.

I use a regular array instead of a numpy one, but it should work the same way.

```py
a = [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 15]
m = 2


def index_repeated_length( list, length ) :
    previous = None
    count = 1
    for i, element in enumerate(list) :
        if element == previous :
            count += 1
        else :
            previous = element
            count = 1

        if count >= length :
            yield i - length + 1

print( list( index_repeated_length(a, m) ) )
```

Output:

```
[2, 6, 11, 12, 17, 18]
```

Since it's never sorted you have to iterate through it, so the complexity should be linear O(n)

Answer (score 0):

I found this one, quite simillar to the otherone posted, but it should work. It only work if the array is sorted

```
def find(a,m):
    index=[]
    prev=0
    n =1
    for i in range(1,len(a)):
        if a[prev] == a[i]:
            n+=1
            if(m==n):
                index.append(i-m+1)
                n=1
        else:
            n=1
        prev=i
    return index if len(index)>0 else None
find(a,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check for consecutive similar values in an unsorted array this method will still work:

```
import numpy as np

nums = np.array([11, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 15])

m = 3

equals = []

for ii in range(len(nums)):
    if ii >= m:
        sliced = nums[ii-m:ii]
        if np.unique(sliced).size == 1:
             equals.append(sliced)

print(np.array(equals))
```

This will give the output for m=2:

```
[[ 2  2]
[ 5  5]
[ 9  9]
[ 9  9]
[13 13]
[13 13]]
```

This will give the output for m=3:

```
[[ 9  9  9]
[13 13 13]]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use a recursive function:

```
def recursive_repeat(arr, k):
    if k == 1:
        return np.flatnonzero(arr)
    else:
        new_arr = np.zeros(arr.size - 1)
        mask = arr[1:] == arr[:-1]
        new_arr[mask] = arr[:-1][mask]
        return recursive_repeat(new_arr, k-1)


recursive_repeat(a, 2)
Out[]: array([ 2,  6, 11, 12, 17, 18], dtype=int64)

recursive_repeat(a, 3)
Out[]: array([11, 17], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

a `numba` njit'ed function:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def find_repeats(arr, n):
    indices = []
    current = arr[0]
    count = 0
    for idx, item in enumerate(arr[1:]):
        if item == current:
            count += 1
            if count >= n-1:
                indices.append(idx)
        else:
            count = 0
            current = item
    return indices if indices else None

b = np.array([0, 11, 2, 2, 3, 40, 5, 5, 16, 7, 80, 9, 9, 9, 1, 11, 12, 13, 13, 13, 4, 5])

print(find_repeats(b, 2))
# [2, 6, 11, 12, 17, 18]

print(find_repeats(b, 3))
# [12, 18]
```

Less elegant but fast, especially for smaller array sizes - `simple_benchmark` comparison vs. [Divakar's functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59664154/10197418):
[image: benchmark]